# MVC: Javascript confirm for delete action not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm pretty new to MVC and Javascript; I'm trying to make a delete action work; I'm using an ActionLink with a Javascript function for confirmation. The JAvascript confirm doesn't work, the delete action is fired even when I press Cancel; additionally, I cannot seem to be able to use [HttpDelete] verb for the action: I need to pass two parameters to the Delete action but after applying @Html.HttpMethodOverride(Http.Delete) on the action link it searches
for an URL with just one parmaeter: id.

Here is my code: action link

```
 @Html.HttpMethodOverride(HttpVerbs.Delete)
  @Html.ActionLink(
                "Delete", 
                "Delete", 
                new {id=notification.Id, typeId=notification.TypeId}, 
                new {onclick="confirmDeleteAction()"})

function confirmDeleteAction() {       
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the notification ?');        
}
```

Delete action:

```
   [HttpDelete]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id, int typeId)
    {
        Service.DeleteNotification(id, typeId);

        NewIndexViewModel model = Service.GetNewIndexViewModel();
        return View("Index", model);
    }
```

Comment: for passing two parameters to Delete Method you have to add an entry in Route.config file

Comment: Visit [blog](http://www.achtmaal.com/blog/html-actionlink-and-http-put-delete-verbs) If you want to use verbs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 @Html.ActionLink(
            "Delete", 
            "Delete", 
            new {id=notification.Id, typeId=notification.TypeId}, 
            new {onclick="return confirmDeleteAction();"})
```

Comment: That worked, thanks ! Only one problem left: making the action work when using HttpDelete verb; Any idea why I can't pass two parameters to an action merked with the HttpDelete verb ?

Comment: @OctavianEpure Try to remove verb then it will work in simple MVC

Comment: I know it works without the verb, I just wanted to use the HttpDelete verb to avoid using GET. I found an article here which explained the security reasons for this. Also I would like to avoid POST, because I already have a submit button on the form. This being a complex index view from which multiple actions can be fired: add, edit, delete, archive items, I didn't want to over-complicate it with multiple post actions and also use a safe way to make a delete. Otherwise, I can use a GET delete action and hope for the best :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel the default behaviour of the browser when the user clicks cancel. You can do this by returning the result of `confirmDeleteAction()` to your `<a>` tag:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
                "Delete", 
                "Delete", 
                new {id=notification.Id, typeId=notification.TypeId}, 
                new {onclick="return confirmDeleteAction()"})
```

For clarity, I added the `return` keyword to your `onclick` handler which will return the result of `confirmDeleteAction()` to the browser -

`true` = perform the default behaviour of the link

`false` = do nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can do this type by also.

```
@Html.ActionLink(
                "Delete", 
                "Delete", 
                new {id=notification.Id, typeId=notification.TypeId}, 
                new {onclick="confirmDeleteAction(" + notification.Id + ")" })


function OnDeleteClick(id) {
                    var ActionID = id;
                    var flag = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');
                    if (flag) {
                return true;
                }
        else{
        return false;
        }
```